# Center all gridview data in Android

Tags: android, gridview

I have this following gridview

set with

```
 android:gravity="center"
 android:numColumns="3"
 android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
```

now my adapter contains 5 data

so the view  looks likes this

[image]

is there a away to show it something like this?

[image]

Comment: Not sure this is possible with the GridView widget. It is created specially to avoid this kind of design and takes the whole width available. Maybe you should create a GridLayout or 2 LinearLayout instead.. or the "heavy" way: create a custom GridView.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Fllo is correct. 
You should use one LinearLayout with orientation set to horizontal for each row that you need.